# what is the optimal way to save table script in bigtable for prod environment

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Please let me know what is the optimal way to save table script in bigtable for prod environment.
Example: Like in database, we can save .sql script and execute it using the shell file.

Is there any similar way to save the table ddl script in bigtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and define the table using the CBT command line tool and once you've settled on your schema, you could put those commands into a shell file. There is no way to export a schema currently.

The CBT tool can create tables, column families, garbage collection, row splits, so it should give you all the features you need.
Here is an example from the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#create_a_table

```
cbt createtable <table-id> [families=<family>:gcpolicy=<gcpolicy-
expression>,...]
   [splits=<split-row-key-1>,<split-row-key-2>,...]
  families     Column families and their associated garbage collection (gc) policies.
               Put gc policies in quotes when they include shell operators && and ||. For gcpolicy,
               see "setgcpolicy".
  splits       Row key(s) where the table should initially be split

    Example: cbt createtable mobile-time-series "families=stats_summary:maxage=10d||maxversions=1,stats_detail:maxage=10d||maxversions=1" splits=tablet,phone
```